# Generate a new email for each hit in elastalert

Tags: elastalert

I am using ElastAlert for alerting via email when there is an error every 10 mins. There is an errorCode for each error. 
Is it possible to generate an email for each errorCode?

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the following somewhere in your file:

```
realert:
    minutes: 0
```

By default, this value is set to 1, so once an alert is sent, elastalert ignores any other matches for the next minute. Any new logs after that minute expires are acknowledged and another alert sent. If, say, elastalert found 100 logs within a minute, but none after that, it would only alert you only once, but if there were 2 logs two minutes apart, an alert would be sent for each.